# jQuery Ajax preloaded should fire at certain point

Tags: jquery, preloader

I have a preloader which loads some images using jQuery and Ajax:

```
$.ajax({

  type: 'GET',
  url: 'preloader.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  success: function( data ) {

    fileNames = [];
    preloadImgs = [];

    arr = $('.rotator').map(function(){
      projectName = $( this ).attr( 'class' ).split(' ')[1].replace( '-img', '' );
      return eval( 'data.' + projectName + 'FileNames' );
    });

    function preload( a ) {
      for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        preloadImgs[i] = new Image();
        preloadImgs[i].src = a[i];
      }
    }

    preload( arr );

  }

});
```

I want this preloader to fire at a certain point in my HTML markup (there are way more images after this certain point in the HTML which shall be loaded afterwards).

I included the preloader at this right point but all the preloader images only get loaded after all other images are loaded.

How can I achieve the preloader to load the images when I want?